# for /f run powershell escape characters

Tags: automation, cmd

When I run the following in cmd prompt, it works fine

```
pushd "C:\Converter"
for /f "delims=" %g in ('dir "C:\Toconvert" /b /s /ad') do (powershell .\BatchConvert.ps1 "%g" 10)
popd
```

It executes the command successfully.
This is the output:

```
C:\Converter>(powershell .\BatchConvert.ps1 "C:\Toconvert\Prego!PDF" 10 )
```

When I tried running the same command in a .bat file, it fails. Using cmd line to run the bat file I find this is what it is generating:

```
C:\Converter>for /f "delims=" \Toconvert" /b /s /ad') do (powershell .\BatchConvert.ps1 "g" 10)
```

Why is it dropping off the "%g in ('dir "C:" before the brackets and why is it dropping off the % in the do command? How do I escape characters to get this to work as a .bat?

Comment: `%` must be doubled as `%%` when used in batch files

Comment: Perfect! I've been beating my head against the desk trying to google what the issue was. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

% must be doubled as %% when used in batch files –  dbenham May 17 '13 at 12:39